# Laravel 5 comment block

Tags: laravel-5, comments

I found before few months some video on Laracast which explain comment blocks can replace some functionality in Laravel 5. I think it was different way of defining properties or something like that, it was new feature in Laravel 5, but I can't find now that video, anyone know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you saw a video about annotations in Laravel 5. Route annotations and Event annotations. They are in laracasts.com, but this worked for Laravel 5 alpha version. I don't think it's useful now.

Comment: Is that removed from other Laravel versions?